# Creating new Android fingerprint for authentication

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I'm trying to make app that use fingerprint authentication to check attendance for employee. the app uses device_id, user name, location, time and send them to back end if authentication successful.

The problem is that it accept any fingerprint stored in the device which mean I can leave my device at work and make the device recognize my friend fingerprint so he can take my absence.

So I'm trying to figure if there any way to make the app take one fingerprint only when user create account and send it to back end and use this fingerprint later in app not these fingerprints stored in the device?

Comment: perhaps a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57657816/is-there-anyway-to-identify-which-fingerprint-used-for-unlocking-accessing