# Is there anyway to identify which fingerprint used for unlocking/ accessing?

Tags: android, biometrics, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric

Suppose i've enrolled 5 fingerprints in my phone. I need to check which of the 5 fingerprint is used for login to my application. Or any way to check the fingerprint if it's not the primary fingerprint.

Comment: There is no "primary fingerprint" in Android's implementation. All fingerprints are considered equal, and app developers do not know which one the user used.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this behaviour is not available in fingerprint API as for the API it's just authentication data  and receive authenticated result from Android device..